# Как обьединить два фрейма с несколькими условиями?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два фрейма данных:

таблица № 1 **задание**:

| Код Тмц | ТКА | Заказ-наряд | Дата | кол |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001231564 | 3610 | Завод_1 | 01.09.2021 | 1 |
| 123449847 | 1474 | Завод_1 | 02.09.2021 | 3 |

Далее есть вторая таблица № 2 **график**:

| Материал | ТКА | 01.09.2021 | 02.09.2021 | ... | 30.09.2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001231564 | 3610 |  |  |  |  |
| 89798461 | 1474 |  |  |  |  |

Необходимо чтобы данные (именно значения колонки `кол`) из таблицы № 1 при условии равенства по полям (Код Тмц = Материал, ТКА = ТКА, и соответсвующей даты) попали в таблицу № 2.

Например код = 001231564 присутсвует в обеих таблицах и значение ТКА = 3610 у обоих одинаково, далее дата в обеих таблицах аналогично присутствует!

[image: Примерно так схема будет выглядеть]

Comment: Исходные данные в вопросе  должны быть в воспроизводимом виде.

Comment: исправил отображение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос, но из следующего фрейма:

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]:
      КодТмц   ТКА Заказ-наряд        Дата  кол
0    1231564  3610     Завод_1  01.09.2021    1
1  123449847  1474     Завод_1  02.09.2021    3
```

можно получить такой, воспользовавшись [DataFrame.pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
res = (df
       .drop(columns="Заказ-наряд")
       .pivot_table(index=["КодТмц", "ТКА"], columns="Дата", 
                    values="кол", aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0)
       .reset_index())
```

результат:

```
In [24]: res
Out[24]:
Дата     КодТмц   ТКА  01.09.2021  02.09.2021
0       1231564  3610           1           0
1     123449847  1474           0           3
```

Comment: Насколько понял, ТС нужно pivot в фиксированые столбцы, а не те, что в первой таблице присутствуют.

Comment: 0xdb, столбцы можно отфильтровать. А вообще я не уверен, что ТС правильно описал задачу. Судя по картинке значение "кол: 3" попадает в первую строку, а судя по описанию должно попасть во вторую

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как провернуть такую хитрую манипуляцию, посмотрю что предложат знатоки pandas. От себя могу предложить такой вариант:

из таблицы №2 делаем таблицу без дат, потом делаем слияние с таблицей №1 по ключевым столбцам, потом строим сводную по датам, получаем похожий результат:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a','date1',10],[2,'b','date2',20],[1,'b','date1',20]],columns=['a','b','date','num'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a'],[2,'b']],columns=['a','b'])

df3 = df2.merge(df1,on=['a','b'],how='outer').pivot(columns='date',values='num',index=['a','b']).fillna(0)
print(df3)
```

вывод:

```
date  date1  date2
a b               
1 a    10.0    0.0
  b    20.0    0.0
2 b     0.0   20.0
```